# How do you use getopt() with non option arguments

Tags: c, bash, stdin, getopt

I am trying to use getopt() for a program that requires either an "e" or "d" option to select encrypt or decrypt then takes a key to be used for either on.  My problem is im not sure how to handle the key with getopt().  I have read much of of the man getopt() stuff and numerous other article at this point.  I currently get a floating point error and core dump and am recieveing the warning message:

cypher.c: In function ‘main’: 
cypher.c:14:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘getopt’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] 
/usr/include/getopt.h:152:12: note: expected ‘char * const*’ but argument is of type ‘char ***’ 
cypher.c:28:13: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Below is the actual code any help is appreciated.

```
include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main(int argc, char **argv[]){

  int e,x; 
  int i=0;      
  int c=fgetc(stdin);
  //  int n=strlen(key);
  int encrypt;

  while((x = getopt (argc, argv, "ed")) != -1){
    switch (x){
    case 'e':
      encrypt=1;
      break;
    case 'd':
      encrypt=0;
      break;
    default:
      fputs("you broke it\n",stderr);
      exit(1);
    }
  }
    char key[100];
    key[100]= argv[optind++];
    int n = strlen(key);

    if(encrypt == 1){
      while(c != EOF){
         c= fgetc(stdin);
         e=(c - 32 + key[i % n]) % 95 +32;
         fputc( e, stdout);
         i++;
      }
    }
    else{
      while( e != EOF){
         c = fgetc(stdin);
         c=(e - 32 -key[i % n] +3 * 95) % 95 +32;
         fputc(c, stdout);
         i++;
      }
    }
  exit (0);
 }
```

Comment: @hek2mgl, man pages suck if you are a newcomer, so downvoting, sucks too ...

Comment: I've downvoted nobody here. I think this man page is indeed helpful, as it comes with examples and good explanations. It doesn't *suck*, give it a try. I also read it, nice one. I've explicitly posted `man 3 ...` as I wanted to show that typing just `man getopt` would give you the man page of the shell program with the same, which is a different thing and also behaves differently than the C function. Happy option parsing! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you want to separate option handling into two steps:

1. Collect all options and do any preprocessing on them (such as checking their validity) and storing them as necessary in variables or structures.
2. Actually taking action based on the full set of options encountered.

So basically you will probably want to set a global variable (such as `opt_mode = ENCRYPT` or `opt_mode = DECRYPT` or something similar), and store the key as necessary. Then after all option processing is done, actually do the encryption or decryption based on the `opt_mode` variable.

Comment: Thank you, that makes almost to much sense.  You have saved me from numerous more hours of beating my head against a wall.

Answer (score 0):

Most new comers do Linux don't even know about `man`, there is no `man` in windows.
In addition the package might not be installed my the Sysadmin. If you can install packages on your machine, install the package:

```
sudo apt get install manpages-dev # on debian based systems
```

It's a usefull resource, you can find a list of all possible man pages doing:

```
 dpkg -L manpages-dev
```

And here is where is what you are looking for:

```
$ dpkg -L manpages-dev| grep getop
/usr/share/man/man3/getopt.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/getopt_long_only.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/getopt_long.3.gz
```

Here is a good example with clear text, in *addition* to man pages (which tend to brevity)...

http://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/c-getopt-example/

Comment: yeah `man 3 ... ` is really helpful! Beginners should know about. good answer!

Comment: BTW: try "apropos getopt"

Answer (score 0):

[getopt(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) has a very good example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int flags, opt;
    int nsecs, tfnd;

   nsecs = 0;
    tfnd = 0;
    flags = 0;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "nt:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'n':
            flags = 1;
            break;
        case 't':
            nsecs = atoi(optarg);
            tfnd = 1;
            break;
        default: /* '?' */
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-t nsecs] [-n] name\n",
                    argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

   printf("flags=%d; tfnd=%d; optind=%d\n", flags, tfnd, optind);

   if (optind >= argc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected argument after options\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   printf("name argument = %s\n", argv[optind]);

   /* Other code omitted */

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```